# Per-entity Lua scripts in games?

Tags: c++, lua, entity, game-engine

I'm using Lua for scripts in my C++ game.  I want to be able to attach scripts to entities, and based on which functions are defined in the script, register for callbacks which will run the script functions at the appropriate time.

I believe that I can encapsulate different scripts from each other, by making the "script" into a table.  Basically, `... lua source code ...` would become `ScriptName = { ... lua source code ... }`.  Then instead of calling `func()`, I'd call `ScriptName.func()`, and thus two scripts defining the same function (aka registering for the same event) wouldn't trample over each other.

My problem now is in encapsulating different entities sharing the same script.  Obviously I don't want them to be sharing variables, but with what I'm doing now, any variable defined by a script would be shared by every instance of that script, which is just really bad.  I could maybe try something similar to my above solution on the source level, by wrapping every script with `EntityID.ScriptName = { ... }` before compiling it.  Something tells me there's a better way, though, I just don't know it.

Another factor is that scripts need to be able to reference entities and scripts/components relative to a specific entity.  If I use the above method the best solution to this would be passing entity IDs around as strings which could reference the table specific to that entity, I think?  At this point I really have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Maybe switch to more object conception, in other words code will be reusable with instance? Im after "intelectual exercise" switching from "Script" concept to object notation in Groovy platform. Direfent language, problem similar (sorry, no english spelling)

Answer (score 0):

In order for a script to interact with a C++ object, the typical approach is to have the C++ code expose the object to Lua as a userdata (a wrapper for a pointer) and provide C++ functions that the script can call, passing the userdata as parameter. In the C++ code, that userdata gives you the object that the function should to operate on. It's equivalent to a "this" pointer.

You usually do this by putting the C++ functions into a metatable associated with the userdata, so they can be called like methods in the Lua code (i.e. `objectIGotFromCpp:someMethod('foo')`.

> ScriptName.func(), and thus two scripts defining the same function (aka registering for the same event) wouldn't trample over each other.

Rather than relying on accessing globals or naming conventions, ect. it's much cleaner to simply provide a callback that Lua scripts can use to register for events.

> If I use the above method the best solution to this would be passing entity IDs around as strings

No reason. An entity in your C++ code is a pointer to an object on the heap. You can pass that pointer directly to Lua as userdata. Lua can pass that back to your C++ code and give you direct access to the object, rather than going through some object-to-ID mapping.

Comment: This doesn't really address my main concern tho,which is a single script shared by multiple entities. Each script would define variables, and each entity sharing a script would trample over each other.

Comment: When you compile a script it produces a function. A function can be passed parameters which are local variables and it can create new local variables within its scope. As with functions in virtually all languages, those local variables are unique to each invocation of the function; they are maintained on separate stack frames. So what does running the script in the context of a particular entity *mean*? If you pass the entity to the script (i.e. you call the script's function with an entity to operate on), any locals it modifies will not affect other invocations of the script.

Comment: If you're talking about *global* variables accessed/modified by the script, then of course they're going to get trampled over. That's why [globals are bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

Comment: I need to be able to maintain some state from one invocation to the next.  I also need to be able to define parameters which could be set from the game editor or from a different entity's script.  Kinda like defining variables inside a class - they aren't global, because they belong to that class, but their state is maintained across function calls and are independent of any other instance of that class.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like functional programming, where no state is kept track of behind the scenes, and every variable or pointer is passed as arguments or return values to functions.  I have no interest in functional programming.

Comment: "What you're describing sounds like functional programming"  Not at all. If you need global state, by all means have it, but be careful about threading. If you need state per entity, then *store it in the entity*. If you want state that's visible only to a particular function, then use a closure. Local variables in the script don't factor into it at all.

Comment: I want state per entity, but I want that state to be defined by the script.

Comment: Then using a closure per Entity.